# Misplaced alignment tab character with eledpar's \stanza in command argument

Tags: macros, parallel, eledmac

I tried defining a command to enter parallel text/translation with eledpar to avoid having to write all the code for parallel typesetting (both for code clarity and because I'm lazy).

So I did try this:

```
    %XeTeX document
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}

    \usepackage[english,latin,german,francais]{babel}

    \usepackage{eledmac}
    \usepackage{eledpar}

    \begin{document}

    \setstanzaindents{1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0}

    \begin{pairs}
      \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
    \stanza
    First verse&
    second verse\&
        \endnumbering
      \end{Leftside}
      \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
    \stanza
    First translation&
    second translation\&
        \endnumbering
      \end{Rightside}
    \Columns
    \end{pairs}

    %Up to this part, everything works as expected

    \newcommand{\trad}[2]{
    \begin{pairs}
      \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
        #1
        \endnumbering
      \end{Leftside}
      \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
        #2
        \endnumbering
      \end{Rightside}
    \Columns
    \end{pairs}
    }

    \trad{
    \stanza
    First verse&
    second verse\&
    }
    {
    \stanza
    First translation&
    second translation\&
    }

    \end{document}
```

The first part, which is the basic code, works as expected. The second part, however, yields a

```
    Section 2  (./minimalstanza.2)
   ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
   <argument>  \stanza First translation&
                                   second translation\& 
   l.58 }
```

Any idea why, and how to fix this?
The command with its argument should yield exactly the same code as the regular block.

A same example with regular text starting and ending with \pstart an \pend as arguments works perfectly. A stanza alone outside a pairs environment works fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\stanza` command changes the meaning of `&` into an *active character*. This makes it impossible to place `\stanza` text using `&` in the argument to another command, unless some precaution is taken.

In your case the simplest trick is to use `\scantokens` that will reread the argument and disregard the already assigned category codes:

```
%XeTeX document
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,latin,german,francais]{babel}

\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}

\begin{document}

\setstanzaindents{1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0}

\begin{pairs}
  \begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\stanza
First verse&
second verse\&
\endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}
  \begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\stanza
First translation&
second translation\&
\endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
\Columns
\end{pairs}

%Up to this part, everything works as expected

%\newcommand{\trad}{\begingroup\catcode`&=\active\innertrad}
%\newcommand{\innertrad}[2]{%
\newcommand{\trad}[2]{\scantokens{%
  \begin{pairs}
  \begin{Leftside}
  \beginnumbering
  #1
  \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}
  \begin{Rightside}
  \beginnumbering
  #2
  \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
  \Columns
  \end{pairs}
  \endinput}
}

\trad{
\stanza
First verse&
second verse\&
}
{
\stanza
First translation&
second translation\&
}

\end{document}
```

Note that loading `xunicode` and `xltxtra` is not recommended any more.